# SuseVM on MS Hyper-V vs standalone OS

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, hyper-v

We are using SuseVM Linux on a MS HyperV  server to host our website (Apache2.2). We've been having issues with response times, especially when server load gets heavy, we're talking 3k-10k unique visits per day.

In your opinion, would it be best to:

1. Move to an outside host?
2. Install on a standalone Linux server using another distro?
3. Any other ideas?

Comment: You have framed this question as "Hyper-V vs. stand-alone," but your real question is that your web server is falling over and you don't know where the bottleneck is. Without the most basic information on RAM utilization, load averages, disk IOPS, upstream bandwidth utilization, etc., no one in the world is going to be able to help you fix this in an intelligent way.

Comment: The network admin claims that the server *should* be handling things perfectly. But reality doesn't match that. We know that there are some small issues with our Magento cart running slow and we cannot fix that at this time but it seems that even more of the site continues to get unreasonably slow during peak visitation times.

Comment: See above: "Without the most basic information on RAM utilization, load averages, disk IOPS, upstream bandwidth utilization, etc., no one in the world is going to be able to help you fix this in an intelligent way."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest trying to profile where things are slowing down - is the VM spending most of its time waiting for disk?  Is the network stack not working well?  It's possible that a fix could be as simple as changing a NIC or storage driver, so some additional details would be helpful to better answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the limited information that you have provided, you (and/or your network administrator) do not yet have the skills necessary to manage your own web server. Therefore, your best course of action is to switch to an outside web hosting provider.

This is no cause for shame: most small and medium-sized companies use outside providers for web hosting even if they *do* have the requisite in-house expertise. Companies do this because outside providers that *specialize* in web hosting can provide better performance, uptime, and security monitoring than one would expect from a typical in-house web server.

Be sure that whatever plan or package you choose is:

1. Fully managed
2. Scaled appropriately for the amount of traffic that your site receives
3. Not an "unlimited" plan (all hosting plans have usage limits, but some hosting companies lie)

You will need to be *extremely careful* about how you manage the DNS cutover from the old site to the new site. Some web hosting companies (e.g. Liquid Web) will help you to perform a clean migration from your existing site at no additional cost.